# Why is my application starting up in more than 2 minutes?

Tags: java, jar, java-8, java-7, startup

I'm running a graphical java application made with swing on my windows 7 64 bits computer.

My application is a runnable jar file that I launch from my command prompt by using the following command:

```
C:\path\to\jre\java.exe -jar myProg.jar
```

My problem is that, I get huge performance performance issues when I'm using JRE8 32bits while not when using JRE7 32bits or JRE8 64bits.
Note that the application is runned with the same jar file ; the only difference is that it's being ran by different JREs.

I tried different JRE8 version and the problems persists...

When I compare both output when using the "-verbose" argument, I see that I get more than 1500 outputs with text : '[Loaded xxxxxx from shared objects file]' for the JRE7 while I get none for JRE8.
Mayby it may be somehow linked ?

Does anyone have an idea on what the problem could be ?

---

Here are some outputs from the JRE7

```
[Loaded MainFrame.MainFrame$XtrFileFilter from rsrc:./]
[Loaded java.awt.event.HierarchyListener from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.InterruptedException from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.io.FileWriter from shared objects file]
[Loaded javax.swing.CellEditor from shared objects file]
[Loaded javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.image.RenderedImage from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.image.WritableRenderedImage from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.image.BufferedImage from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.util.IdentityArrayList from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Window$Type from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAccessor$WindowAccessor from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Window$1 from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAccessor$FrameAccessor from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Frame$1 from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.ComponentOrientation from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Component$3 from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded javax.swing.ImageIcon from shared objects file]
[Loaded MainFrame.Simulation.Simulation from rsrc:./]
[Loaded MainFrame.Optimization.Optimization from rsrc:./]
[Loaded MainFrame.Convergence.Convergence from rsrc:./]
[Loaded java.awt.event.WindowEvent from shared objects file]
[Loaded MainFrame.Menu from rsrc:./]
```

Here are some JRE8 outputs

```
[Loaded MainFrame.MainFrame from rsrc:./]
[Loaded java.util.EventListener from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.event.ActionListener from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded javax.swing.Action from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded javax.swing.UIManager from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded javax.swing.UIManager$LookAndFeelInfo from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.OSInfo from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.OSInfo$WindowsVersion from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.OSInfo$1 from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.OSInfo$OSType from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Toolkit from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAccessor$ToolkitAccessor from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Toolkit$4 from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAccessor from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Toolkit$5 from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.ResourceBundle$Control from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.CoreResourceBundleControl from c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar]
```

---

I runned a Xshare:dump for both JRE7 and JRE8 and I got the following results:

JRE7:

```
Loading classes to share ... done.
Rewriting and unlinking classes ... done.
Calculating hash values for String objects .. done.
Calculating fingerprints ... done.
Removing unshareable information ... done.
Moving common symbols to metadata section at 0x3a033570 ... done.
Moving vmSymbols to metadata section at 0x3a1d2170 ... done.
Moving the remaining symbols to metadata section at 0x3a1d3478 ... done.
Moved 44361 symbols, 1703760 bytes.
Moving pre-ordered read-only objects to shared space at 0x38a30000 ... done.
Moving read-only objects to shared space at 0x38e129b0 ... done.
Moving string char arrays to shared space at 0x38e20cd8 ... done.
Moving pre-ordered read-write objects to shared space at 0x39430000 ... done.
Moving read-write objects to shared space at 0x399e8fb0 ... done.
Moving String objects to shared space at 0x39a3e920 ... done.
Read-write space ends at 0x39a7dd28, 6610216 bytes.
Updating references to shared objects ... done.

An error has occurred while processing the shared archive file.
Unable to create shared archive file c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\client\classes.jsa.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to use shared archive.
```

JRE8:

```
Allocated shared space: 27394048 bytes at 0x14a00000
Loading classes to share ...
Preload Warning: Cannot find javax/swing/JComponent$2
Preload Warning: Cannot find javax/swing/RepaintManager$1$1
Preload Warning: Cannot find javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalLookAndFeel$MetalLazyValue
Preload Warning: Cannot find javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalLookAndFeel$MetalLazyValue$1
Preload Warning: Cannot find javax/swing/text/AbstractDocument$InsertStringResult
Preload Warning: Cannot find sun/awt/windows/WToolkit$3$1
Preload Warning: Cannot find sun/java2d/Disposer$2
Preload Warning: Cannot find sun/java2d/d3d/D3DScreenUpdateManager$1
Preload Warning: Cannot find sun/java2d/d3d/D3DScreenUpdateManager$1$1
Loading classes to share: done.
Rewriting and linking classes ...
Rewriting and linking classes: done
Number of classes 2383
    instance classes   =  2369
    obj array classes  =     6
    type array classes =     8
Calculating fingerprints ... done.
Removing unshareable information ... done.
Shared Lookup Cache Table Buckets = 4108 bytes
Shared Lookup Cache Table Body = 50352 bytes
ro space:   5650016 [ 47.7% of total] out of  12582912 bytes [44.9% used] at 0x14a00000
rw space:   5396096 [ 45.6% of total] out of  12582912 bytes [42.9% used] at 0x15600000
md space:    753892 [  6.4% of total] out of   2097152 bytes [35.9% used] at 0x16200000
mc space:     34032 [  0.3% of total] out of    131072 bytes [26.0% used] at 0x16400000
total   :  11834036 [100.0% of total] out of  27394048 bytes [43.2% used]
```

Comment: Have you tried running the same code on another machine ? With the same JRE8?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same scenario...

Comment: Can you post some examples of what is in the xxxxx part? And what is a "graphical Java application"? AWT / plain Java2D? SWT? Swing? JavaFX?

Comment: @Gimby: I added details to my description. It's a swing application. It runs smoothly with JRE7 but it's taking easily 5 minutes to start up with JRE8 32bits. I tried to run it with JRE8 64bits and it starts up instantly too...

Comment: Are these Windows machines? If so it may be an issue with DirectX. Try adding the `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false` option and see if that changes anything. If that works, try updating (in this order) your video drivers and DirectX.

Comment: what is the memory usage, if it is 32bit and you are causing it to swap to disk and thrash that would explain it the easiest!

Comment: AlvinThompson: I tried adding your option but it's not changing anything... 
@JarrodRoberson: I monitored the run with 'VisualVM' and my app used 15Mb out of 16Mb head size for JRE8 while it's using 12Mb out of 16Mb for JRE7... ; I also checked in my task manager for the java.exe process and it doesn't use more than 34Mb

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [Shared Class Data](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/class-data-sharing.html) archive of your installation is missing or corrupted.

You may try as suggested in the documentation under [“Regenerating the Shared Archive”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/class-data-sharing.html#skip2content)

> To regenerate the archive, log in as the administrator; in networked situations, log on to a machine of the same architecture as the Java SE installation and ensure that you have permission to write to the installation directory. Then execute the command
>
> `java -Xshare:dump` Diagnostic information will be printed as the archive is generated.

Note that you can enforce the use of the shared data to get an error message (rather than slowdown) if it fails, as described on the same page:

> #### Manually Controlling Class Data Sharing
>
> The class data sharing feature is automatically enabled when conditions allow it to be used. The following command line options are present primarily for diagnostic and debugging purposes and may change or be removed in future releases.
>
> `-Xshare:off`
>
> Disable class data sharing.
>
> `-Xshare:on`
>
> Require class data sharing to be enabled. If it could not be enabled for various reasons, print an error message and exit.
>
> `-Xshare:auto`
>
> The default; enable class data sharing whenever possible.

Comment: I added the Xshare:dump results to my question. There indeed a difference between JRE7 and JRE8 dumps. JRE8 seems not to be able to find some classes... What would it mean ?

Comment: I wouldn’t bother about these nine classes. The important point is that after you ran `java -Xshare:dump` once, you should run your application using `-Xshare:on` and it should 1.) succeed, 2.) start faster, 3.) together with `-verbose` print `[Loaded … from shared objects file]` for some classes…

Comment: It's indeed loading some classes from shared objects files but it's still not starting up faster... (more than 3 minutes...)

Comment: Then it’s time to start a run with profiler to find out where the majority of time is spent.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, I had this problem on a windows 2012 server. The only solution for me was to uninstall java and then reinstall it.